# Is correct to set CSS property to html tag?

Tags: html, css

I can actually set the background-color of the html tag. I didn't know it was possible and I don't understand if it's logically correct, I thought the body was the only one responsable to contain  and the "first" rendered tag. I thought html tag was just a wrapper but it looks different. So,

> - What exactly represents the html tag?
> - Why can I set it's background-color?
> - Will it give me problems?

I resized body to a 1024 x 768 size and want to set its background color to white, while html page to black, it's quite nice in this way... I would like to know if I must use div for this (I hate a lot of divs!!!)

Comment: You should use a div for this because it feels like an improper use of the HTML syntax. Body to me means the entire body of the page. You might also want to see if applying a background-color to the html element is compatible with older browsers

Comment: @James Hay: The HTML tag represents the window viewport. I see no reason not to use it for styling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A browser *will* render it that way. Styles on the actual HTML element are perfectly fine. In fact, the [default style sheet for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) sets the `<html>` element to be `display: block`. It *is* a visible element and it can be stylized.

Adding styles to the root element doesn't change its semantic meaning, only how it's displayed. As long as you're not altering the semantic meaning of elements, you're fine. Style away.

Comment: That's really interesting and nice! Thanks a lot, I feel safer now.

Comment: The second paragraph is why `display: table` is so cool these days. Unfortunately some people just don't get it...

Comment: Anyway, there are some subtle differences between applying styles to `html` and `body` which are covered in [a number of other questions here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bbody+%2Bhtml+%5Bcss%5D).